# Present simple and present progressive to describe current action, limited duration, temprary state

Tags: present-tense

Are the simple present and the progressive interchangeable in the sentences below?

For example, 1. "They live/are living in poverty" (a current state-is expressed by the progressive but with the present simple it refers to a fact. So if I am talking about a current state I shouldn't use the present simple.

Changes: 2. "The climate is getting warmer" (the climate gets warmer isn't probably natural if I am talking about a current situation and the changes in it).

Current trend: 3. "Schoolchildren are carrying heavy schoolbags." If I say "Schoolchildren carry" it would refer to a fact. It's not wrong if I want to express that.

4. Temporary action/current situation and limited duration if all three mean the same thing: "I am living in Paris" and "I am woking in a bank" ( usually I work in an office). If I always work there then the progressive isn't correct.

If my comments are correct then  either tense is correct in my sentences but it depends on what we wish to express.

I am not sure temporary actions,  current situations and limited duration all three mean the same thing.